# Using member declaration with enable_if?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, visual-c++-2012

I need conditional using member declaration.

```
template <bool> struct B;
template <> struct B<true> { void foo(); };
template <> struct B<false> { };

template <typename T>
struct A : public B<is_default_constructible<T>::value> {
    using B<is_default_constructible<T>::value>::foo();

    void foo(int) {}
};
```

This obviously doesn't work, because `B<bool>::foo` is not defined
in half the cases. How can I achieve that? To have `B<>::foo()`
visible in `A<T>` scope beside foo(int)?

Comment: what is it exactly that you want? for `A::foo(void)` to only be defined if `B<>::foo(void)` is not defined?

Comment: @RichardHodges I read it as the opposite: `A::foo(void)` should be defined iff `B<>::foo(void)` is defined.

Comment: exactly, I want to have A::foo(void) if T is default constructible (therefore B<>::foo(void) is defined, since B<true>);

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I'm sure it's won't be the best but it gets the job done.

```
struct A {
    void foo(int) {}
};
```

`struct A` should contain methods you want defined in both cases.

```
template <bool> struct B;
template <> struct B<false> : A {};
template <> struct B<true> : A { 
    using A::foo;
    void foo() {} 

};
```

In case of `B<false>`, only `void foo(int)` is defined. In case of `B<true>`, both `void foo(int)` and `void foo()` are defined.

```
template <typename T>
struct C : public B<is_default_constructible<T>::value> {};
```

Now I don't have to worry about `B<is_default_constructible<T>::value>::foo()` not being defined in certain cases.

```
class D { D() = delete; };

int main()
{
    C<int> c1;
    c1.foo(1234);
    c1.foo();
    // both methods are defined for C<int>

    C<D> c2;
    c2.foo(1234);
    // c2.foo(); // undefined method

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use specialization.

`enable_if` can't be used for that. You need to specialize `struct A` too.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool> struct B;
template <> struct B<true> { void foo(); };
template <> struct B<false> { };

template <typename T, bool default_constructible = std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>
struct A : public B<default_constructible> {
    using B<default_constructible>::foo;

    void foo(int) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, false> : public B<false> {
    void foo(int) {}
};
```

#### Avoiding duplicate code for foo(int)

If `foo(int)` will have the same functionality in both cases, you may want to derive it from another base struct:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool> struct B;
template <> struct B<true> { void foo(); };
template <> struct B<false> { };

template<typename T>
struct C {
  void foo(int) {}
};

template <typename T, bool default_constructible = std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>
struct A : public B<default_constructible>, public C<T> {
    using B<default_constructible>::foo;
    using C<T>::foo;
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, false> : public B<false>, public C<T> {
    using C<T>::foo;
};
```

#### Removing that ugly bool

Finally, to remove that bool from `struct A`'s template parameters, you may want to forward the responsibility of selecting the overloads of `foo` to a base class. This also has the advantage of not duplicating code for other `struct A`'s members you may want to add.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool> struct B;
template <> struct B<true> { void foo(); };
template <> struct B<false> { };

template<typename T>
struct C {
  void foo(int) {}
};

template <typename T, bool default_constructible = std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>
struct base_A : public B<default_constructible>, public C<T> {
    using B<default_constructible>::foo;
    using C<T>::foo;
};

template<typename T>
struct base_A<T, false> : public B<false>, public C<T> {
    using C<T>::foo;
};

template <typename T>
struct A : public base_A<T> {
    // Other members.
};
```